# Unable to install Tryton Server on windows

Tags: python-3.x, tryton

I am new to `Tryton`. I am insalling a `trytond` with a command

> pip install trytond

. everything goes right but when I try to check the version with command

> tryrond --version

. It give me the following error. Also can someone guide me through steps of installation.

> Program 'trytond' failed to run: No application is associated with the
> specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
>
> - trytond -c ./tryton.conf -v -d tryton --de
> - 
> - trytond -c ./tryton.conf -v -d tryton --de
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
>   ```

Answer (score 0):

trytond is a Python script that must be run by Python.
For the record, it is really not recommended to run Tryton server on Windows (any core developer does that).

Comment: should I try it on Linux??

Comment: Any UNIX system should be easier to setup.